# Mismatch between imshow and imwrite for the same figure in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

Output of an image processing operation will be shown correctly when it is presented in the MATLAB environment using `imshow (Output,[])` (the following image).

[image]

But when it is stored using `imwrite` function, it will be unsatisfactory and different from the previous image (following image).

[image]

It seems there is a problem with thresholding; However I never experienced such an error before.

How it is possible to save the output of imshow using imwrite function?

Comment: Do you understand what `[]` does in `imshow`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I know that but I have not experienced such a problem previously but the OP just edited.

Comment: Notice how `imwrite` doesn’t have the `[]` argument. Hence the difference. You need to modify the image just like the `[]` parameter of `imshow` does before calling `imwrite`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, Thanks for the comment. Do you know it a good idea? putting the output of imshow (Output,[]) in a variable and imwrite that.

Comment: You said you know what the `[]` parameter does. Just replicate that. It’s a simple computation.

Comment: Or better yet, don't mess with the image and just display it consistently.